# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 6

Tags: java

This code throws -

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 6 exception
```

When I try to create a `.sql` file from the large CSV files (800 rows of records). If I use small CSV records (5 rows of records), it works as expected and I am able to create a `.sql` file.

## stack trace:

```
1:INSERT INTO bofa_fund1(${keys}) VALUES(${values})
2:INSERT INTO bofa_fund1(Originator Loan Number,Servicer Loan Number,Pool_Num,Fund_Date,Originator,Current Servicer,Gross Rate,Original Balance,Cutoff Balance,Paid Thru Date,Next Due Date,First Pay Date) VALUES(${values})
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 6
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:470)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:737)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceFirst(Matcher.java:861)
    at java.lang.String.replaceFirst(String.java:2146)
    at org.db.createSQLfromCSV.loadCSV(createSQLfromCSV.java:156)
    at org.fileimport.CreateSQLServlet.doPost(CreateSQLServlet.java:44)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Can you please help me to solve this problem?

```
public class createSQLfromCSV {


    public static final char DEFAULT_SEPARATOR = ',';
    public static final String NEXT_LINE_STRING ="\n";

    public static final String NEXT_TWO_LINE_STRING ="\n \n";

    private static final String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO ${table}(${keys}) VALUES(${values})";
    private String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE ${table}(${keys})";

    private static final String TABLE_REGEX = "\\$\\{table\\}";
    private static final String KEYS_REGEX = "\\$\\{keys\\}";
    private static final String VALUES_REGEX = "\\$\\{values\\}";


    private Properties prop = new Properties();

    private File inputfilePath;
    private File outputFilePath;
    private File archiveFolder;


    public void loadPropertyfile(){      
        InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("org/properties/config.properties"); 
        try {      
              prop.load(in);
              inputfilePath = new File (prop.getProperty("sourcedir"));
              outputFilePath = new File (prop.getProperty("outputdir"));
              archiveFolder = new File (prop.getProperty("archivedir")); 
            } 
        catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Parse CSV file using OpenCSV library and load
     */
    public void loadCSV() throws Exception {
        loadPropertyfile();

        System.out.println("inputfilePath:" + inputfilePath);
        if( inputfilePath.isDirectory() && inputfilePath.list().length == 0)
        {
                throw new Exception("No file found on the server");
        }

        else if(inputfilePath.isDirectory() && inputfilePath.list().length == 1 )
        {

            for (final File fileEntry : inputfilePath.listFiles())
            {
                if (fileEntry.isFile() && !fileEntry.getName().endsWith(".csv"))
                {
                    System.out.println("The File" + fileEntry.getName() + " is not a CSV format file");
                }
                if (fileEntry.isFile() && fileEntry.getName().endsWith(".csv"))
                {
                                        String inputFileName = fileEntry.getName();
                    String csvFilename = inputfilePath + "\\" + fileEntry.getName();

                    String  OutputfileName = inputFileName.replace(".csv", "")+"_"+getDateTime()+ ".sql";
                    File outputfile = new File (outputFilePath, OutputfileName );

                    CSVReader csvReader = null;
                    BufferedWriter writer =   new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( outputfile));


                    try {

                        csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename), DEFAULT_SEPARATOR);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        throw new Exception("Error occured while executing file. "
                                + e.getMessage());
                    }

                    String[] headerRow = csvReader.readNext();

                    if (headerRow == null) {
                        throw new FileNotFoundException(
                                "No columns defined in given CSV file." +
                                "Please check the CSV file format.");
                    }

                    String[] nextLine;
                    String tableName = inputFileName.replace(".csv", "");
                    String dbVarType = "VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)";

                    String createTablequery = CREATE_TABLE.replaceFirst(TABLE_REGEX, tableName);
                    createTablequery = createTablequery
                            .replaceFirst(KEYS_REGEX, StringUtils.join(headerRow, " "+dbVarType+","));
                    System.out.println("createTablequery: " + createTablequery);
                    writer.write(createTablequery);
                    writer.write(NEXT_TWO_LINE_STRING);
                    writer.write("LOGGING " + NEXT_LINE_STRING);

                    writer.write("TABLESPACE"+" "+ '"' + "BIC_DATA" + '"'+" "+NEXT_LINE_STRING);
                    writer.write("PCTFREE 10 " +NEXT_LINE_STRING);
                    writer.write("INITRANS 1 " +NEXT_LINE_STRING);
                    writer.write("STORAGE " +NEXT_LINE_STRING);
                    writer.write("(" +NEXT_LINE_STRING);

                    writer.write ("INITIAL 81920 "+NEXT_LINE_STRING);
                    writer.write("NEXT 1048576 "+NEXT_LINE_STRING);
                    writer.write ("MINEXTENTS 1 "+ NEXT_LINE_STRING);
                    writer.write ("MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 "+ NEXT_LINE_STRING);
                    writer.write ("BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT "+NEXT_LINE_STRING);
                    writer.write(")" +NEXT_LINE_STRING);

                    writer.write("SET DEFINE OFF"+ NEXT_LINE_STRING);

                    while ((nextLine = csvReader.readNext()) != null)
                    {

                        String insertquery = SQL_INSERT.replaceFirst(TABLE_REGEX, tableName);
                        System.out.println("1:" + insertquery);
                        insertquery = insertquery
                                .replaceFirst(KEYS_REGEX, StringUtils.join(headerRow, ","));
                        System.out.println("2:" + insertquery);
                        insertquery = insertquery.replaceFirst(VALUES_REGEX,StringUtils.join(nextLine, ",") ) +";"+NEXT_LINE_STRING;
                        System.out.println("3:" + insertquery);
                        writer.write(insertquery);

                    }

                    writer.close();
                    csvReader.close();
                    MoveFiles.moveTheFile(inputfilePath,archiveFolder); 
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Multiple files found on the server");
        }
    }

    private  final static String getDateTime()  
    {  
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss");  

        return df.format(new Date());  
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the error and highlight the line in this class where it occurs.

Comment: 1:INSERT INTO bofa_fund1(${keys}) VALUES(${values})
2:INSERT INTO bofa_fund1(Originator Loan Number,Servicer Loan Number,Next Due Date,First Pay Date) VALUES(${values})
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 6
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:470)
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:737)
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceFirst(Matcher.java:861)
 at java.lang.String.replaceFirst(String.java:2146)
at org.db.createSQLfromCSV.loadCSV(createSQLfromCSV.java:156)

Comment: the error occurs in this line : 
 insertquery = insertquery.replaceFirst(VALUES_REGEX,StringUtils.join(nextLine, ",") ) +";"+NEXT_LINE_STRING;
 it is printing 100s of rows and suddenly throwing error.

Comment: I updated the stack trace in my original post which is easy to read.

Comment: You did not even remove the commented out code … clean up your mess and ask again.

Comment: Can you accept the answer if you're happy with it?

Comment: @Dave Morrissey - Yes. I just did. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One of your CSV lines has `$6` in it. When you try to do a regex replacement, java interprets this as a reference to a capturing group, and looks for that group in the regex match. In this case it isn't there.

Try escaping the replacement like this:

```
insertquery = insertquery.replaceFirst(VALUES_REGEX, Matcher.quoteReplacement(StringUtils.join(nextLine, ","))) + ";" + NEXT_LINE_STRING;
```

Comment: +1 for `Matcher.quoteReplacement`.

Comment: Dave Morrissey - Thank you for explaining the problem and provide me the code fix. It is working as expected now. Thanks again!

Comment: Luke Woodward - Thank you for the response. I am all set now.